# Jackson: how to include null value property in JSON serialization

Tags: java, null, jackson, response

I'm trying to generate a JSON response using my own Java entity classes together with Jackson annotations. Two key values must be `null` in my JSON response but if I set them to `null` they disappear from JSON. I'm limited to Jackson version 1.9.13 unfortunately.

I already tried set values to `null`, using

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)
```

My response entity:

```
public class Response {

@JsonProperty("data")
private Data data;

@JsonProperty("error")
private Error error;

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(PgSoftAuthData data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Error getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(PgSoftError error) {
    this.error = error;
}
}
```

I'm trying to generate response like this:

```
Data data = new Data();
data.setName("Name");
data.setTime(null); // This key dissappear from JSON

Response responseSuccess = Response();
responseSuccess.setData(data);
responseSuccess.setError(null); // Error object disappear from JSON
```

I would like to get following response:

```
{
    "data" : {
        "name" : "Name",
        "time" : null
    },
    "error" : null
}
```

Comment: Where have you added `@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)`?

Comment: I added it to Error attribute in Response entity.

Answer (score 7):

Add [JsonInclude](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#ALWAYS) to relevant classes `Response` and `Data`

(updated using @ThomasFritsch comment)

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
```

> Value that indicates that property is to be always included, independent of value of the property.

Comment: and add it also to `Data` class

Comment: I can use only
    @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)
and it doesn't work.

Comment: Somehow not working in Jackson version 2.11.0 as well

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answers!
As I mentioned I'm limited to Jackson 1.9.13 and I tried multiple combinations with following Jackson annotation but unsuccessfully:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)
```

Then I used following:

```
@XmlElement(nillable = true)
```

annotation on error and name attributes and it works. Now I get proper JSON response.

Error attribute solution:

```
@XmlElement(nillable = true)
@JsonProperty("error")
private Error error;
```

Comment: How can i do the same to a HashMap?