# I want ignored field by @jsonignore to be null while serialization

Tags: java, spring, null, jackson

I have one to many relationship with company and user. I am using @jsonignore for avoiding infinite recursion but one property is ignored during serialization. Instead of ignoring, I want that property as null in the json. How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54180616/jackson-how-to-include-null-value-property-in-json-serialization same question is here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.