# Convert an object to JSONObject with null values in Java

Tags: java, json

An object convert into JSONObject, Without ignoring the null values and keys. I want to include the null values. How to solve this problem.

myObject = {"id":123, "name": null}

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myObject);
```

Later jsonObject only contains id, but I want to keep both id and name after the conversion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson: how to include null value property in JSON serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54180616/jackson-how-to-include-null-value-property-in-json-serialization)