How to see all field in a graphql request in spring boot
I'm migrating my Spring Boot application to version 3.3.0. For GraphQL, I now use the following dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>15.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>13.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-extended-scalars</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>

Before the migration, I had all of my fields in the response. Now, if a field is null, it does not appear in the response.
Example with a user entity:
type User {
  id: Int!
  name: String
  description: String
  greeting : Greeting
  listFriend: [User]
}

type Greeting {
  id: Int!
  code: String
  description: String
}

Before migration :
{
  id: 1
  name: "username"
  description: null
  greeting : null
  listFriend: null
}

After migration :
{
  id: 1
  name: "username"
}

How to keep field if there value is null ?

Just wondering do you add desired fields into your query? If yes I suggest check jackson nulls includion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54180616/jackson-how-to-include-null-value-property-in-json-serialization

Add this configuration solved this problem
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    /*
     * Configure the Jackson ObjectMapper.
     */
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule, Jdk8Module jdk8Module, 
                                     JsonNullableModule jsonNullableModule, ProblemModule problemModule, 
                                     ConstraintViolationProblemModule constraintViolationProblemModule, 
                                     Hibernate6Module hibernate6Module) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // Register the modules
        objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
        objectMapper.registerModule(jdk8Module);
        objectMapper.registerModule(jsonNullableModule);
        objectMapper.registerModule(problemModule);
        objectMapper.registerModule(constraintViolationProblemModule);
        objectMapper.registerModule(hibernate6Module);
        
        // Configure null fields
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
        // Optionally configure the serialization of dates
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}

